# Connect to mysql server through ssl in Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, ssl, ssl-certificate, zend-db

1. Single DB connection (resource configuration) from `application.ini`:

   ```
   resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
   resources.db.params.host = "mysql1"
   resources.db.params.username = "dbuser"
   resources.db.params.password = "dbpass"
   resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
   ;resources.db.???
   ```
2. Multiple DB connection (resource configuration) from `application.ini`:

   ```
   resources.multidb.mysql1.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
   resources.multidb.mysql1.host = "mysql1"
   resources.multidb.mysql1.username = "dbuser"
   resources.multidb.mysql1.password = "dbpass"
   resources.multidb.mysql1.dbname = "dbname"
   ;resources.multidb.mysql1.???
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure if you have noticed, but there are actual question marks (???) in my code :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe connecting to MySQL with SSL is currently supported in Zend. However, Zend Issue Tracker [ticket #6140](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6140) may be of help to you.

Comment: Yeah, I found that before... I guess there is no proven solution yet, so I'll have to test it by myself... Thanks anyway!