# MySql SSL connection with Zend-Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, ssl

I'm pretty new to Zend-Framework, but I managed to build a simple site in my PC with 2 pages that show the content of a table in a local database. 
The problem is that when I installed the site on the server, it didn't work because in the production server the connection to the local mysql server must be established using SSL.

I searched for the keys that I need to add to the **application.ini** to enable the ssl connection but I couldn't find any in the ZendFramework documentation. 
Here is the code of my **application.ini**

```
    resources.multidb.config.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
    resources.multidb.config.host = "localhost"
    resources.multidb.config.username = "Administrator"
    resources.multidb.config.password = "xxx"
    resources.multidb.config.dbname = "config"
    resources.multidb.config.default = true
```

do you know if the ZendFramework supports ssl connection to mysql server and how to configure it? if no: is there some workaround?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794627/connect-to-mysql-server-through-ssl-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's currently supported. [Carl Welch](http://framework.zend.com/issues/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=cwelch) patched it in [ticket #6140](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6140) (see the `library.diff` attachment), however, changes don't seem to be in the trunk yet.

I suggest to vote for the issue (you have to log in first).